# Using a check box to determine the value of a textbox

Tags: forms, ms-access, checkbox

I am trying to figure out how to use a check box to determine the value of a textbox.

If the check box is yes I wish a text box to display the contents of another check box (unbound, on different tab in the same form), if it's not I want it to default value.

Comment: Maybe use an IIf() expression in textbox Control Source. If you want to save this result to field, that will require code (macro or VBA). But if it can be calculated when needed. probably no need to save. When you have code with specific issue, post question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *AfterUpdate* event of the determining checkbox:

```vb
Private Sub ThisCheckbox_AfterUpdate()

    Dim Checked As Boolean
    Dim Value   As String
    
    Checked = Me!ThisCheckbox.Value
    
    If Checked Then
        Value = Format(Me!AnotherCheckbox.Value, "Yes/No")
    Else
        Value = Me!TheTextbox.DefaultValue
    End If
    Me!TheTextbox.Value = Value
    
End Sub
```